# Check liveliness while waiting for API response

Tags: python, async-await, fastapi

I am trying to create a Fast API. the program itself uses some API whose response might take more than 2 minute, while waiting when liveliness and readiness check is called, the function doesn't respond. I am also using async in the program.
SO how can I make them respond while waiting for response.

I tried Async sor synchronise calling, but it's not working as expected.